# Java regular expression extract special string between two string

Tags: java, matcher

currently I wish to extract a Token that is content in string format.
I've already seen [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902290/java-regular-expression-extract-string-between-two-words), but in my context, I don't manage to extract my token.
I've got this code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SOAPParsing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "<BinarySecurityToken Id=\"TotoToken\">Kqdsqd/Jxugtqsk6Ws3q3sd54sq6d4q6sd4qs6d4qs6dq6sd98d69qdq9dsq7d98q7sdqdq7qsddq7Mw2RMmhevkJt/4q6sd7qsIRveuTTqdqsa/zxqsdqdqNg==</BinarySecurityToken>";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("BinarySecurityToken\\\\Id=\"TotoToken\">\\s:\\s(.+?)\\</BinarySecurityToken>");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        } else {
            System.out.println("nothing ..");
        }
    }
}
```

How I can fix my problem ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Try your regex in some online tool first, i.e. without the Java escaping. As an example: what do you think `\\ ` (non-escaped version) after `BinarySecurityToken` should match?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I get nothing

Comment: For one thing the part of your Regex, \s:\s is looking to match [whitespace]:[whitespace] which doesn't appear in your string.  So even if everything else were correct (which I doubt), it still wouldn't match.  Like Thomas said, Google "Regex Tester" and get the pattern to work before you mess with stuffing it in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your regex:

`"<BinarySecurityToken Id=.*>(.*)</BinarySecurityToken>"`